# Datetime.format('yyyy-MM-dd') subtracts a day

Tags: apex, datetime, format

Is there a reason that the below returns 2017-11-30? I know changing it to Datetime.newInstance fixes it, but I'm mostly wondering why this happens.

```
Datetime myDate = Date.newInstance(2017, 12, 1);
system.debug(myDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd'));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mplax,

when you create the date via Date.newInstance it is creating the 1st of dec as per GMT.

Once you call format on it. It applies your locale settings which would not be as GMT and your timezone might be behind GMT by few hours. So it is showing you 30th Nov.

E.g.
If you add few hours to it then it will start showing the date you expected. The hours that you might to add is based on what is the offset of your timezone with the GMT.

[image]

Comment: Very interesting. I wonder if there's ever a time when this is preferred behavior... Thanks for your help!

Comment: @mplax There is a format date option that keeps the time in GMT so that it wont apply your custom locale as well: `datetime.formatGMT(dateFormatString)`